# mouseenter , mouseover or any mouse event does not working on my script?

Tags: javascript

```
let box = document.getElementById("box");
box.addEventListener("mouseenter", mouseFunc);

function mouseFunc(e) {
  console.log("event " + e.type);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the html for your `box` element?

Comment: Do you have any error logged in your [dev-tools console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console)?

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the script, are you adding the event listener to `$(document).ready()` or some other way? Also, what does your html look like for the `box` element?

I just tested your code exactly as you posted and it works fine for me.

```js
let box = document.getElementById("box");

box.addEventListener("mouseenter", mouseFunc);

function mouseFunc(e) {
  console.log("event " + e.type);
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
 test box
</div>
```

I suspect you may be using `box` as a class and not an id, in which case you want `getElementsByClassName` and then you need to add the event listener for each element

```
let box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
    box[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", mouseFunc);
};
```

Comment: If they were indeed using box as a class, they would need to iterate over the result of `document.getElementByClassName("box");`.

Comment: This is the HTML element that I running currently . <div id="box"></div></body>